# Knockout binding in style

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is is possible to bind in side a style with knockout? See the example:

```
<div style="background: url('!!INSERT IMAGE LINK HERE!!!') no-repeat; padding-left: 25px">
```

I know i can make a string in my view model that contains it all, but i would like to keep the css seperated from my view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a style binding to set the background depending on a property on the view model, see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html

Having said that I generally think it's better separation if you use the css binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html and define a css class to represent the state.